# SQL - Grab Detail Rows as Columns in Join

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is my query thus far:

```
select C.ACCOUNTNO,C.CONTACT,KEY1,KEY4 from contact1 C
left join CONTSUPP CS on C.accountno=CS.accountno
where 
C.KEY1!='00PRSP' 
AND (C.U_KEY2='2009 FALL' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 SPRING' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 J TERM' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 SUMMER')
```

Now, I have another table (CONTSUPP) which contains multiple detail records for each record in CONTACT1. For example - High School GPA, SAT, ACT, etc. I need to pull these values into the same row as my contact1 results - but determine the column header based on information within the column. For example, I know I could do this:

```
select C.ACCOUNTNO,C.CONTACT,KEY1,KEY4,STATE from contact1 C
left join CONTSUPP CS on C.accountno=CS.accountno
where 
C.KEY1!='00PRSP' 
AND (C.U_KEY2='2009 FALL' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 SPRING' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 J TERM' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 SUMMER')
```

Don't ask why (please) - but state holds the grade values. The problem is that this gives me grades without telling what type of grades, so I need to do something like this (pseudo):

```
select C.ACCOUNTNO,C.CONTACT,C.KEY1,C.KEY4,
  STATE as GPA when CS.CONTACT='High School'
  STATE as SAT when CS.CONTACT='Test/SAT'
  ..
from contact1 C
left join CONTSUPP CS on C.accountno=CS.accountno
where 
C.KEY1!='00PRSP' 
AND (C.U_KEY2='2009 FALL' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 SPRING' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 J TERM' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 SUMMER')
```

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
    C.ACCOUNTNO,
    C.CONTACT,
    C.KEY1,
    C.KEY4,  
    HichschoolCS.State as HighSchool,  
    TestSatCS.state as Test


from 
    contact1 C
    left join CONTSUPP HichschoolCS on C.accountno=HichschoolCS.accountno 
        and HichschoolCS.contact = 'High School'
    left join CONTSUPP TestSatCS on C.accountno=TestSatCS.accountno 
        and TestSatCS.contact = 'Test/SAT'
where 
    C.KEY1!='00PRSP' 
    AND (C.U_KEY2='2009 FALL' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 SPRING' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 J TERM' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 SUMMER')
```

Update: Added example of only using the highest SAT score

```
select 
    C.ACCOUNTNO,
    C.CONTACT,
    C.KEY1,
    C.KEY4,  
    HichschoolCS.State as HighSchool,  
    TestSatCS.state as Test


from 
    contact1 C
    left join CONTSUPP HichschoolCS on C.accountno=HichschoolCS.accountno 
        and HichschoolCS.contact = 'High School'
    left join (SELECT MAX(state) state, 
        accountno
        FROM
            CONTSUPP TestSatCS 
        WHERE 
            contact = 'Test/SAT'
        GROUP
            accountno) TestSatCS
    on C.accountno=TestSatCS.accountno 

where 
    C.KEY1!='00PRSP' 
    AND (C.U_KEY2='2009 FALL' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 SPRING' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 J TERM' 
    OR C.U_KEY2='2010 SUMMER')
```

Comment: Two quick issues. One is that I'm trying to add two values together like so: OFF_SAT_COMP.LINKACCT + SLF_ACT_COMP.COUNTRY as 'SAT - Composite' - but it just joins the two values - doesn't add them.
Secondly, this query seems to result in multiple rows in some cases for some individuals.

Comment: I added a sample for only including the highest score. As for you other problem, I"m guessing linkacct and country aren't numeric fields. You'll need to do the conversion before adding e.g. CAST(linkaccount as int) + CAST(country as int)